# Enabling Squid delay pool eats up the entire memory

Tags: squid

I am using "squid-3.1.8-1.el5" in my CentOS 5 32 bit system.
In normal condition Squid uses 85m - 90m, but when I enable the 
delay pool parameters the memory usage suddenly rise up 2GB. The 
memory keeps on increasing until the system is out of resource.

The following are my delay pool settings:

delay_pools 1

delay_class 1 1

delay_access 1 allow all

delay_parameters 1 192000/192000

Is there anything I am missing here or is it a bug with Squid ?

Comment: I have not seen this when I have used delay pools.  Is there any other error messeges?

Comment: I am able to figure this out, it is a bug with Squid and it is fixed in Squid 3.1.10. Upgrading squid to latest fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
delay_access 1 allow all !CONNECT
```

That work for me. From what I researched Squid has a bug and adding !CONNECT fixed it and the the problem no longer occurs.

Comment: Could you add the link to where you found that this was a bug?

Comment: I'd like to see it too. I have an old Fedora 12 presenting this problem.

Comment: I had the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04 Server 64bit with recent squid3, 2GB RAM Core2Duo E8500 CPU. System load is always below 0.05. It is a small network with a couple of hosts using squid3 with very few ACLs, used for caching purposes only. After adding delay pools I experienced %99 CPU usage for squid3. Browsing was almost impossible because of very high latency. However adding !CONNECT  resolved the problem. If someone has the link to bug report, I'd like to add myself.